# Fetching a crash report from remote users via email in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash-reports, acra

I'm building an app and I want to let my friends test it for a while to find out some bugs that I didn`t think about.

I want my users to be transparent about that action. purely pressing the button and the whole bug report will be sent to my email account.

During my time here figuring what is the best way to achieve my goal I encountered the ACRA lib.
Unfortunately, most of the information is about 6 years old and is not working for me

This is what I end up trying:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
            mailTo = "reports@yourdomain.com", //My email address goes here
            mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
            resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ACRA.init(this);
        ...

}
```

While I added the dependency to the Build.Gradle

```
implementation 'ch.acra:acra-advanced-scheduler:5.5.1'
```

Android studio still can`t resolve the following:

> ReportsCrashes,formKey,mailTo,ReportingInteractionMode,crash_toast_text

Is there a way to easily fix this so I can get the crash reports in an easy way to my email?
I fear that ACRA is deprecated and I`m wasting my time.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're following an old guide relating to how to set up the ACRA library. Use the official one instead:

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

It seems to me you're using the wrong dependencies and annotations - I assume what you need is:

```
implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acraVersion"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:$acraVersion"
```

And also might want to use `@AcraMailSender` and `@AcraToast` notifications. Hope this is good enough of a starting point for you.